# How to center 2 or more divs on the same line? (css)

Tags: html, css, centering

I've a little problem with css centering:/
I have 2 or more divs on the same line and  I would to their width be equal with each other.
So, if there are 2 divs then the 1. and the 2. divs have to have equal part from the area (50% and 50%) and these divs should be centered.

I have a code below, but it's not working.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="xy">First</div>
    <div class="xy">Second</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.xy {
    display: inline;
    margin: auto;
}
.main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` like:

```css
.xy {
  display: table-cell;/*set display to table-cell*/
  width: 50%;/*set the width to 50%*/
}
.main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  display: table;/*set display to table*/
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="xy">First</div>
  <div class="xy">Second</div>
</div>
```

If you want text to be center too you can add `text-align: center` in `.xy`:

```css
.xy {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;/*add text-align center*/
}
.main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="xy">First</div>
  <div class="xy">Second</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.xy {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    widht: 50%
}
```

Change to inline-block and give it a width in %.